# Vim latex-suite is not changing the environment properly. How can I fix this?

Tags: vim, environment, latex-suite

A am using the latex-suite plugin for vim but there is one problem, best illustrated with an example.  Suppose I have the following environment:

```
\begin{theorem}
  Blah blah blah.
\end{theorem}
```

Now, if I want to chang it to a lemma, I press Shift-F5 within the theorem environment and type 'lemma' at the prompt.  But it then gives me TWO slashes like so:

```
\\begin{lemma}
  Blah blah blah.
\\end{lemma}
```

Does anybody know how I can get this working properly so that there is only one slash after the change?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have a similar problem, only instead of adding backslashes, it removes them.

Comment: Sorry, i haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is an old latex-suite bug. Not sure if it's fixed in the latest versions (it has been reported), but in any case going to `ftplugin/latex-suite/envmacros.vim:281` and replacing the `\\` with a `\` on each line did the trick for me. You should end up with:

```
    let first = '\begin{' . a:env . '}'
    let second = '\end{' . a:env . '}'
```

Comment: The bug hasn't been fixed yet but your advice worked.  Thank you.

Comment: The work version on [github](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/blob/master/ftplugin/latex-suite/envmacros.vim#L781) has correct this.